# How would I replace 15 with a string. I am trying to replace any number in a list that is divisble by 15 with the string "go"?

Tags: python

```
def b_function(low, high):
    g = []
    for i in range(low,high):
        if i % 3 ==0 or i % 7 ==0 or i % 15 ==0:
            #print(str(g) +" ",end = " ")
            g.insert(len(g),i)
            #i.replace("15","boo")
        #if i % 15 ==0:
            #g.append("Boo")
            print(g)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    num_1 = int(input("Please input the lower limit:\n"))
    num_2 = int(input("Please input the upper limit:\n"))
    c = b_function(num_1,num_2)
```

I am letting the user input the range and how would I replace all the numbers that are divisible by 15 with string "go".

Comment: Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: Why do you want to *replace* 15 with "go"? Why do you not just *not insert 15* in the list, and insert "go" instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you run your code once? It raises error and may not work like you expected.

```
# there are more conditions than number divisible by 15, 
# the if statement execute for the first condition that is True,
# in this case, all number divisible by 3
if i % 3 ==0 or i % 7 ==0 or i % 15 ==0:

# so you will have a list of numbers divisible by 3, even if it is a list of numbers
# divisible by 15, and you successfully replace, you only get a list full of "go"
# as there are no other numbers inserted under if statement
g.insert(len(g),i)

# raise AttributeError here because integer input doesn't have replace function, 
# even it works, you only replace 15 not 30 or 45 etc. and the word will be "boo"
i.replace("15","boo")

# your print function is in the for-loop, so if there are 6 numbers divisible by 15,
# the list will be printed 6 times, is that what you want?
print(g)
```

Please also aware in range(a,b), b is exclusive, for example, range(0,100) have number from 0 to 99 not include 100.

May be you want something like this?

```
def b_function(low, high):
    g = []
    # high+1 to include the num_2
    for i in range(low,high+1):
        # directly append "go" to the list when the number is divisible by 15
        # so no need to replace
        if i % 15 == 0:
            g.append("go")
        # regular print out for numbers divisible by 3 or 7
        elif i % 3 == 0 or i % 7 ==0:
            g.append(i)
    # only print the list once after the for-loop
    print(g)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    num_1 = int(input("Please input the lower limit:\n"))
    num_2 = int(input("Please input the upper limit:\n"))
    c = b_function(num_1,num_2)
```

The output will be:

```
[3, 6, 7, 9, 12, 14, 'go', 18, 21, 24, 27, 28, 'go']
```

Comment: I pasted the wrong thing in the template but I have a list and I'm letting the user input the range it wants but if it is divisible by 3 and 7 print it out regular if it is divisible by  15 too replace 15 with "go" when I print the list.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to modify a list is to use a comprehension that creates another list:

```
>>> numbers = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45]
>>> [n if n % 15 else "go" for n in numbers]
[5, 10, 'go', 20, 25, 'go', 35, 40, 'go']
```